# How to do quicksort for my list of data so that it will be sorted alphabetically

Tags: c++, quicksort

I have a project going on, its a student registration system, i have done the most part except the part where i have to do quicksorting to sort my data, the plan is: my program got user to input their names, icno, matric number and their faculty, then if the user choose option '3', the list of data will be sorted alphabetically.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0ecd.png), for example from the image above, the program will sort the data so that "Alex" will be first, i am doing my project in vs-studio and its for my data-structure and algorithm subject

```
void Student::quickSort(string &x,int left, int right)
{
    
    
    int j = right;
    int i = left;
    int mid = x [(left + right) / 2];

    while (i <= j) {
        while (x[i] < mid)
            i++;
        while (x[j] > mid)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(x[i], x[j]);
            i++; j--;
        }
    };
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(x, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(x, i , right);



    displayStudent();
}

void Student::studentName(string x)
{
    x = name[size];

    quickSort(x, 0, x.size() - 1);
}
```

i tried using this code but it never works

Comment: Don't post images of code, errors or otherwise plain text. Use markdown code formatting for these.

Comment: If you are learning C++, Have you looked at std:vector<std::string>? and [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) using "C" style arrays like that is setting yourself up for a lot of unecessary bugs.

Comment: There's a fundamental problem with the code you have posted, it sorts the letters of a string (so 'alex' would sort to 'aelx') but apparently you want to sort the names in a list so 'john, bob, alex' would sort to 'alex, bob, john'. So in other words you need to think a bit more about the **type** you are sorting.

Comment: `studentName` makes very little sense, and I think you should review what you've learned over the last few weeks and read (much) more in your favourite C++ book. (It looks like you have just copied the `quickSort` function from somewhere and tried to guess the rest.)

Answer (score 1):

1. From your description, wouldn't it be better to perform insertion sort so that data is always sorted.

Other things does not make sense. for instance :

```
void Student::studentName(string x)
{
    x = name[size];

    quickSort(x, 0, x.size() - 1);
}
```

Function takes string of `x` and the immediately its overridden with `name[size]`. You probably wanted to do `name[size] = x; size ++;`, assuming name is array of vector and its size is more than that of `size`.

Your function `quickSort` is actually attempting to sort the characters of the string, and, that is not what you want to do, right?.

Essentially you have 2D array of characters as your input, and the quick-sort you are using only operates on 1D array (here, array of characters).

sample code: http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Data-Structure-Algorithm/AQuicksortforstrings.htm

other similar thread:
[Using quicksort on a string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294982/using-quicksort-on-a-string-array)